# My chatbot application is not running on SSL certified server

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io, virtualhost, dialogflow-es

I am able to run the node js with socket.io application on "http://www.example.com" but when I tried to run the same on "https://www.example.com" it won't run and I am getting error as "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present on the requested resource [error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN8tA.png) . I tried creating virtual host on centos hosting on apache web server in /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd.conf, also I have included the following lines in .htaccess Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type" Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" When I open a non-standard port like 3000 and listen on it Getting error while running "port already in use". I am using apache server on centos.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Dialogflow, you can use Google's Firebase Functions. Firebase can handle the hosting and SSL certificate management for you, and respond to HTTP requests.

Here's a sample implementation to get started, if you choose the Firebase route:
https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although we are using different service as our backend.